# Update SQLite table of Android application optimally

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, insert

I am working on an android application using `android:minSdkVersion="14"`. The application receives data as JSON from a server. The data received need to be added to an sqlite table. If a row exists, all fields **except for two** have to be updated. If a row does not already exist in the table, it has to be inserted. I am looking for the most efficient way as regards performance.

The function `insertwithonCoflict()` has been considered but it is not an option since in case of update, it updates all the fields including the two that should not be updated.

The function `replace()` is also not suitable.

I would opt for a **SELECT** to check if the row exists and then an **INSERT** or **UPDATE** but I was wondering if I could optimize the procedure somehow .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two approaches:

- Change the database structure so that the table has only the server data. Put local data (the two columns) in another table that references the server data table. When updating, just insert to the server data table with "replace" conflict resolution.
- Do the select-insert/update logic.

For performance in any case, use database transactions to reduce I/O. That is, wrap the database update loop in a [transaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction%28%29) and only commit it when you've done with everything. (In case the transaction becomes too large, split the loop into transaction chunks of maybe a few thousand rows.)

Comment: Could you please get into a little more detail as regards database transactions to reduce I/O?

Answer (score 0):

A nice solution I use is as follows:

```
long id = db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE, null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
if(id!=-1) db.update(TABLE, contentValues, "_id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
```

This ensures the row exists and has the latest values.